# Can't remove 2XClient using dpkg

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gconf

I have a problem removing 2XClient from Ubuntu 12.04.

This is the output

```
Removing 2xclient ...
Unregistering tuxclient url-protocol handler in gconf tree

(gconftool-2:3905): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Failure during recursive unset of "/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/tuxclient": No D-BUS daemon running

(gconftool-2:3905): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Unregistering tuxclient url-protocol handler in gconf tree
grep: /home/sladjanadj/.dbus/session-bus/660680798d27ff1532041eb700000004-0: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing 2xclient (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 2xclient
Error in function:
```

I tried:

⠀`dpkg --remove --force-all`
⠀`dpkg --purge --force-all`
⠀`dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq`
⠀`apt-get -f`
⠀removing entry from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

Nothing worked. What can I do ?

Comment: Anyone ? I really need your help :|